# Strange behavior while decoding hex characters to ASCII in Java

Tags: java, hex, character, ascii

I wrote a Java program to take the lines of a file, and sort out a specific id which will then be converted to ASCII characters from HEX. Worked great for a couple of files until it found out the "0D" HEX character which seems to be carriage return (no idea what that does).

When it encounters that, it ends the line output (which it shouldn't do). I can't figure out what's happening.

This is the code, which compiles with no error. I've attached a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xqIi.png) with the result.

[image]

The file 1 contains the characters until the ID=xxx:LENGHT=8 and after that the 8 HEX characters needed to convert. after that, the program converts and add the text in the same line. I need them to be on the same line to figure out the pattern.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class FrameDecoder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            // Sortam frameurile cu id-ul tinta

            File fisierSursa = new File("file1.txt"); //Fisierul original
            FileWriter fisierData = new FileWriter("file2.txt");  //Fisierul cu frameurile care au id-ul cautat
            FileWriter fisierTranzit = new FileWriter("file3.txt");  //Fisier cu caractere HEX, care va fi sters.

            Scanner citireSursa = new Scanner(fisierSursa);
            

            while (citireSursa.hasNextLine()){
                String data = citireSursa.nextLine();
                //System.out.println("data = " + data);
                int intIndex = data.indexOf("ID=289");  // idul pe care il cauti
                int intIndex2 = data.indexOf("ID=1313");  //al doilea id pe care il cauti


                if (intIndex != -1 || intIndex2 != -1){
                    char[] text = data.toCharArray();
                    int counter = 0;

                    for (int i=0; i<text.length; i++){
                        if (text[i] == ':' && counter < 5){
                            counter++;
                        }
                        if (text[i] == ':' && counter == 5){
                            fisierTranzit.write(text[i+1]);
                            fisierTranzit.write(text[i+2]);
                        }
                    }

                    fisierTranzit.write("\r\n");
                    fisierData.write(data + "\r\n");
                }
            }

            citireSursa.close();
            fisierTranzit.close();
            fisierData.close();

            // Convertire HEX to ASCII

            FileWriter fisierAscii = new FileWriter("file4.txt");  //Fisier care va contine caraterele ASCII decodate
            File fisierTranzitRedeschis = new File("file3.txt");  //Reinitializam fisierul tranzit pentru a putea citi din el
            Scanner citireTranzit = new Scanner(fisierTranzitRedeschis);



            while (citireTranzit.hasNextLine()){
                String data2 = citireTranzit.nextLine();
                System.out.println("data2 = " + data2);
                if (data2.length() % 2 != 0){
                    System.err.println("Invalid hex string!");
                    return;
                }


                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i=0; i<data2.length(); i=i+2){
                    //Impartim sirul in grupe de cate doua caractere
                    String s = data2.substring(i, i+2);
                    //Convertim fiecare grup in integer folosinf valueOfTheMetod
                    int n = Integer.valueOf(s, 16);
                    //Convertim valoare integer in char
                    builder.append((char)n);
                }

                fisierAscii.write(builder.toString() + "\r\n");
                //System.out.println(builder.toString());

            }

            citireTranzit.close();
            fisierAscii.close();

            //Stergem fisierul 3

            File stergereFisier3 = new File("file3.txt");

            if(stergereFisier3.delete()){
                System.out.println("File 3 deleted successfully");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Failed to delete file 3");
            }


            // Combinam fisierele

            PrintWriter fisierFinal = new PrintWriter("file5.txt");

            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2.txt"));
            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file4.txt"));

            String line1 = br1.readLine();
            String line2 = br2.readLine();

             //loop to copy lines
             //of file1.txt and file2.txt
             //to file3.txt alternatively

            while (line1 != null || line2 !=null){
                if(line1 != null){
                    fisierFinal.print(line1 + "  ");
                    line1 = br1.readLine();
                }

                if (line2 != null){
                    fisierFinal.println(line2 );
                    line2 = br2.readLine();
                }
            }

            fisierFinal.flush();

            //closing resources

            br1.close();
            br2.close();
            fisierFinal.close();

            System.out.println("Merged files succesfully");

            //Stergem fisierul 2 si 4

            File stergereFisier2 = new File("file2.txt");
            File stergereFisier4 = new File("file4.txt");

            if(stergereFisier2.delete() && stergereFisier4.delete()){
                System.out.println("Files 2 and 4 deleted successfully");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Failed to delete files 2 and 4");
            }


        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("No data to print");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Edit: I've cheated a little and place a condition when printing the HEX characters, if encounters 0D, just replacem them with 00. It worked. I'll also try your method, that one seems more ok than mine.

```
for (int i=0; i<text.length; i++){
                        if (text[i] == ':' && counter < 5){
                            counter++;
                        }
                        if (text[i] == ':' && counter == 5){
                            if(text[i+1] == '0' && text[i+2] == 'D'){
                                fisierTranzit.write('0');
                                fisierTranzit.write('0');
                            }
                            else{
                                fisierTranzit.write(text[i+1]);
                                fisierTranzit.write(text[i+2]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of text should be augmented with the text they contain or be replaced by the text they contain if they do not contain other context information. This is because images of text are not searchable or accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The carriage return character `\r` (hex `0D`) is one of the standard line separator characters, and `Scanner.hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()` methods assume it must terminate the current line.

To get more control, set the `delimiter` for Scanner to just the line feed character `\n` and use hasNext/next methods instead of hasNextLine/nextLine methods. For example:

```
Scanner citireTranzit = new Scanner(fisierTranzitRedeschis);
citireTranzit.useDelimiter("\n");

while (citireTranzit.hasNext()){
    String data2 = citireTranzit.next();
    ...
}
```